# Disable highlighting of current line in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio

In Android Studio, the current line under the caret is highlighted:

[image]

Is there a way to disable this feature?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In Android Studio

1. go to `File -> Preferences -> Editor -> Colors and fonts -> General`
2. Select `caret row`
3. Uncheck Background checkbox.

[image]

Comment: As of the current version this option is now at: File -> Settings-> Editor -> Color Scheme -> General -> Editor